# Подскажите разницу между классами Monitor и Mutex

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Теоретический вопрос. Если нам нужно синхронизировать потоки, то  в большинстве случаев наверное достаточно `lock`, это почти то же самое, что класс `Monitor`, а какая разница с классом `Mutex`, неужели только в том, что Монитор это вещь статическая,а для Мутекса нужно создавать экземпляр класса.

Comment: Если кратко, то Mutex - это фича ОС, методы из статического класса `Monitor` - это фича .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `Monitor` работает только в рамках одного процесса. `Mutex`'у же, можно задать идентификатор, который будет единственным для всей ОС.

Например, это полезно, если у Вас запущено два разных приложения, но между ними должна происходить синхронизация (как пример, запись в файл и чтение).

Так же посмотрите вот [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159668/monitor-vs-mutex) вопрос.

P.S. по поводу большинства случаев и использования `lock` - если у Вас есть ожидание задач (`await`) - то `lock` использовать [не получится](https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/).

Comment: Насчет синхронизации и `async/await` -- NitoAsync в помощь.

Comment: @andreycha , я библиотеку использовал, но у нее вроде нет релизной версии под `netstandard2.0`

Comment: @andreycha а в чем преимущество этой либы? Я юзал просто `SemaphoreSlim` для асинхронного лока

Comment: @A1essandro c .NET Standard/.NET Core история следующая -- они разбили библиотеку на несколько разных пакетов. Подробности смотрите [тут](http://embed.plnkr.co/S96X5ZuXrGHa4KASYI3z).

Comment: @tym32167 абстракция. Например, тот же самый `AsyncLock` удобнее использовать с `using`, чем семафор с `try/finally`. Ну и там еще куча полезных классов (например, `AsyncLazy`), которые, по сути, являются просто удобными обертками.

Comment: @andreycha спасибо, гляну на досуге либу