# Синхронизация работы потоков, использование mutex

Tags: c#, синхронизация

Есть класс, выполняющий роль некого общего ресурса:

```
class Source
{
    private static int _count = 0;
    public static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

    public static void Increment(int value)
    {
        _count += value ;
        Console.WriteLine($"Текущее значение count             {_count}");
    }

    public static void Decrement(int value)
    {
        _count -= value;
        Console.WriteLine($"Текущее значение count             {_count}");
    }
}
```

Есть общий класс потока, который, в зависимости от своего названия, производит некоторую работу с ресурсом:

```
class MyThread
{
    Thread thread;
    Random rng = new Random();
    int rngValue;

    public MyThread(string name)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this.Run);
        thread.Name = name;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Поток {thread.Name} вошел в Run");
        if(thread.Name == "Increment")
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Source.mutex.WaitOne();
                rngValue = rng.Next(10);
                Console.WriteLine($"Сгенерировано число {rngValue}");
                Source.Increment(rngValue);
                Source.mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        if(thread.Name == "Decrement")
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Source.mutex.WaitOne();
                rngValue = rng.Next(10);
                Console.WriteLine($"Сгенерировано число -{rngValue}");
                Source.Decrement(rngValue);
                Source.mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine("Неверное имя потока"); }
    }
}
```

Есть точка входа в программу, где я создаю необходимое мне кол-во потоков:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyThread first = new MyThread("Increment");
        MyThread second = new MyThread("Decrement");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Программа не работает корректно, а именно, не смотря на попытку синхронизации с помощью mutex, потоки все равно работают одновременно. Видимо поэтому значение переменной count всякий раз обращается в ноль, так как потоки decrement increment для вычислений используют одно и тоже случайное число. Вопрос в следующем: как устроить синхронизацию потоков таким образом, чтобы выполнялся только один поток в одну единицу времени, и переменная count не обращалась постоянно в ноль? Использовать необходимо именно mutex. Буду также очень признателен, если укажите ситуации, в которых необходимо использовать именно mutex, а не иные средства синхронизации.

Comment: 1) Почему вы используете Mutex, а не обычный монитор (`lock`)? 2) в чем смысл создавать поле `int rngValue;`, если вы его перезаписываете при каждом обращении по сути? Почему бы не сделать его просто локальной переменной? А вообще ваша проблема в том, что вы создаете одновременно два `Random` поля - потому они одно и то же генерируют

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Начальное значение Random() в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-random-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: [ситуации, в которых необходимо использовать именно mutex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/896402/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 я изучаю шиелда, пробую различные средства синхронизации. Я захотел решить данную задачу именно с использованием Mutex. Других причин для его использования нет.

Comment: static Random решил частично мою задачу, теперь числа не обнуляются, спасибо. Но как быть с тем, что два потока все равно выполняются одновременно? В секунду выводится два сообщения с текущим значением count, а должно выводится только одно.

Comment: ну так вы выполните `Thread.Sleep(1000);` до того, как отпустите мьютекс, а не после

Comment: @tym32167, можете уточнить, mutex все таки в каких случаях лучше использовать? Когда он нужен?

Comment: ну, основное, что выделяет мьютекс - это то, что он может быть (а может и не быть) использован для синхронизации между процессами, в то время как, например, монитор - это синхронизация только внутри процесса

Comment: Типичный сценарий использования - это, например, запись несколькими процессами в файл, или, например, запуск только 1 экземпляра приложения - обе задачи требуют синхронизации между процессами

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код корректен, вот результат его выполнения, как видно, значение Count меняется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В рамках одного AppDomain лучше использовать монитор. Он легковестнее.

Comment: Если я закоментирую строки "Сгенерировано число", то раз в секунду буду получать два сообщения о изменении count, хотя должен получать только одно сообщение в секунду

Comment: Кто вам сказал? Чтобы получать одно сообщение в секунду, вам надо Sleep перенести в обоих if перед ReleaseMutex

Comment: Если возьмете инфу из комментариев и скомпонуете шикарный ответ, то я плюсану :)